# Вывод целочисленного массива в файл через fostream

Tags: c, файлы, функции, потоки-данных, fstream

В функции void print_array необходимо реализовать вывод массива через fostream.h (инклюды прописаны). Но даже банальная иницииализация не работает:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("file.txt");
```

Как мне вывести массив?

> array.cpp
>   c:\users\slavek\desktop\kurs_code\array.cpp(66) : error C2065: ofstream: необъявленный идентификатор
>   c:\users\slavek\desktop\kurs_code\array.cpp(66) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "fout"
>   c:\users\slavek\desktop\kurs_code\array.cpp(66) : error C2065: fout: необъявленный идентификатор
>   c:\users\slavek\desktop\kurs_code\array.cpp(67) : error C2065: fout: необъявленный идентификатор
>   c:\users\slavek\desktop\kurs_code\array.cpp(67) : error C2228: выражение слева от ".open" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение

```
int *FindOtvet(int *a, int *b, int size, int size2, int *size3) // 6.1
    {
       *size3=0;
       int* d = (int*)malloc((size+size2) * sizeof(int));

       for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++) 
       for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
         if(b[i] ==  a[j]) 
          {
            d[(*size3)++] = b[i];
            a[j] = 0;
          }
        d = (int*)realloc(d, (*size3) * sizeof(int));

        return d;
    }


    void print_array(int *d, int size3, int select1)
    {

        if (select1 == 1)
        {
      for (int i = 0; i<size3; i++)
      {
        printf("D[%d]= %d ", i, d[i]); 
            printf("\n");
      }
        }
        else if (select1 == 2)
        {
        printf("вывод в файл......");
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("file.txt");
        //как вывести


        }
        else
        {
          printf("Введите 1 или 2\n");
        }
    }
```

---

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` спасет отца русской демократии :) Только непонятно, вы пишете на C - тогда зачем вам эти C++'ные штуки? Используйте `FILE*`!

Comment: Вот именно. Задание на Си, требуют С++ функции. Непонятно что делать.

Comment: FILE * f;
f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
for(int i=0; i<size3; i++)
{
 fprintf(f, " %d", d[i]);
}
fclose(f);
 Тогда получаеся как-то так.

Comment: //fprintf(f, " %d", d[i]); - так работает
 fprintf("D[%d]= %d ", i, d[i]);  // - вот так требует применения приведения i \array.cpp(77) : error C2664: fprintf: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из 'const char [11]' в 'FILE *'
1>        Типы, на которые указывают указатели, не связаны; для преобразования требуется reinterpret_cast, приведение в стиле С или приведение в стиле функции

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант вполне работоспособен:

```
FILE * f = fopen("test.txt", "w"); 
for(int i=0; i<size3; i++) 
{ 
    fprintf(f, " %d", d[i]); 
};
fclose(f);
```

А этот

```
fprintf("D[%d]= %d ", i, d[i]);
```

конечно же не работает из-за того, что вы (почему?!) пропустили файловый указатель `f`. Ну хоть чуть-чуть можно быть внимательней - ведь строкой выше вы его писали?

```
fprintf(f, "D[%d]= %d ", i, d[i]);
```

Если позарез надо через потоки C++ (что за бред!) - то не забудьте о

```
using namespace std;
```

или, если без него -

```
std::ofstream fout("file.txt");
for(int i=0; i<size3; i++) 
{ 
    fout << "D[" << i << "] = " << d[i] << "\n";
};
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Понял, усвоил. И еще вопрос - а как базовым образом заставить файл этот текстовый открыться в окне после занесения результата? Я смотрю команды семейства f, но пока не нашел, то, что мне нужно. Или надо прибегнуть к другим средствам?

Comment: Именно в вашем же окне? Надо его читать и выводить. Но если вы просто хотите посмотреть, что туда записано - откройте его в любом редакторе, типа Блокнота в Windows.

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: Хуже, чем _using namespace std;_, трудно представить совета.